# Dev C++ compilation error, permission denied

Tags: c++, compilation, dev-c++

I want to compile a code program using dev c++ compiler but my compiler didn't compile my code.The program consist of two files one is header and other is implementation .cpp file.
The code i want to compile is correct and working,but it didn't compiling on my pc(windows 7)
Please help

The error which i am getting is

```
  Permission denied 
  ld returned 1 exit status 
  C:\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [Project1.exe] Error 1
```

here is my compile log

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c testProgDoublyLinkedList.cpp -o testProgDoublyLinkedList.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"   

g++.exe testProgDoublyLinkedList.o  -o "Project1.exe" -L"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib" -mwindows  

C:\Dev-Cpp\Bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot open output file Project1.exe: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make.exe: *** [Project1.exe] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

Comment: What's your operating system? you seem to have a permissions problem.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't closed the last execution window you opened, so the file `ld.exe` is still used, and so access to it is not permitted!

Comment: Try to relocate your source tree to some user-writeble location, since it is in "C:\" now, and writing in the root folder of disk is not allowed to applications without explicitly getting permission via UAC

Comment: sorry ,but i have installed new windows on my pc with a new hard drive and this is a first program which i am executing but it isn't compiling

Comment: Don't use Dev-C++, it's highly outdated. Use Code::Blocks instead.

Comment: Don't use Dev-C++, it's highly outdated. Use Visual Studio Express (or higher if you are a student) instead.

Comment: What Griwes said, except that I'd tend to recommend students put a flavor of Linux on a USB stick and learn to use GCC and write their own makefiles instead to start out. Learn to crawl before you walk :)

Answer (score 5):

Try running task manager to determine if your program is still running.

If it is terminate it because that's why your compiler is giving you an error.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 does not let you write directly to the root of `c:\` (among other locations) unless from within a process running with administrator privileges.

The simplest workaround for you is to move your project from `c:\` to another directory -- for example, `c:\projects` will work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the proposed answers in my windows 7
1. run as administrator
2. Killed the process if it is running already
3. Gave full control permission to the project folder
4. Moved to different project folder.
Nothing solved my problem. finally i tried after **disabling avast anti virus**..it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 7**

> If you click save all files button then close and delete the makefile
>   and others except the .cpp, .dev, .c then reopen using either .dev or
>   .cpp or .c and then run it works.

Comment: I've found that generally, the correct answer is don't use Dev-C++ because it's a steaming pile of *bleep* but this would also work. I tutor students that are required to use this compiler and this problem happens with great frequency, even when not using the C: directory as Jon indicated above. It's a pile of garbage and I try my best to talk students into learning how to use GCC, or steer them towards XCode if they have a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the same problem by creating a new folder and saving the project into that new folder. Then I also saved the source file within that same folder and everything finally executed correctly.  It seemed to be a directory issue with finding the files when it was trying to execute.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Dev-Cpp\Bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2........\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot open output file Project1.exe: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

This line here is the computer saying it does not have permission to work with
the specified directory. Either save your work in a new folder which the program
has permission to work with or run your program as an administrator.

Kind of pointless responding to an old issue but if anyone else has this problem
hopefully this will save them some time.

Answer (score 0):

I removed generated exe file from projects folder and error went . I am removing after every rebuld-rerun . wait 1-2 minutes if it is not removing . one time try to remove , it will refuse . leave it and it will disappear itself . meanwhile you can enjoy changes in code . tried everything , only this worked

Comment: you can post your code it will be useful to know your idea