# Dev-C++ giving error for Makefile.win and g++ stopping

Tags: c++, makefile, dev-c++

I have installed Dev-C++, but when I make a C program and run it, it gives me an error, like:

```
C:\Users\Ved\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [Project1.exe] Error 1
```

And when I checked the log it shows the following:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Users\Ved\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Users\Ved\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win" all
gcc.exe main.o  -o "Project1.exe" -L"C:/Users/Ved/Dev-Cpp/lib"  

gcc.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions.

make.exe: *** [Project1.exe] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

I have used Dev-C++ on my friends computer running Windows XP SP3, and it runs fine and gives the output.

I am using Windows 8 64 bit, can I actually run Dev-C++ on 64 bit?
And can this error be fixed?

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10463958/1361836) yet?

Comment: Yes, but the solutions do not work for me.

Comment: Your problem is probably explained by this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12812582/1362568,
and in that case the solution is this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13148384/1362568

Answer (score 0):

I have used the old Dev-C++ in the past and I've have had it break randomly on me at times..

Bloodshed Dev-C++ hasn't been updated for years and development has actually stopped on it.

If you really like the environment consider getting the updated and maintained Orwell Dev C++ that is improved, faster and much cleaner.

This is Solution to Solve error easily

Answer (score 0):

Close All, then Go to Project options and in linker tab write the following and click ok:
-lopengl32
-lfreeglut
-lglu32
Now execute the program

Answer (score -1):

Just close all the other tab in project. It will run normally

Answer (score -2):

Check if in the compiler directory there is **g++.exe**. 
If you can see it go to:

[Installing c++/g++ on Windows](http://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/alee/g++/g++.html)

and download the file **full.exe** then follow the instruction and put the directory in path. After that restart your pc, go to the **cmd** and try to compile there. If it works change the toolchain of the IDE. If you need help contact me :)

Comment: Recommending to go to some random website and download a .exe file? Really?